# IronPython : Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token '=''

Tags: c#, python, .net, syntax-error, ironpython

I have a Python scrirpt and that I am trying to execute from C# code using `IronPython` and I am getting the below error message:

> Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token '=''

Here is my Python code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='c:\\rahul\\example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')

BUCKET_NAME='Rahul'
print("Bucket name :-" + BUCKET_NAME)
```

And here is my .NET C# code:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(); 
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\rahul\appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filePath);
var compiled = source.Compile();
var result = compiled.Execute(scope);
```

I am getting an error from the last line :

> Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token '=''

Any help?

Comment: Which versions of Python and IronPython are you using? I get no errors with the above code.

Comment: Python 3.7.1 and IronPython 2.7

Comment: Which version are you using for both? Did you invoke Python from .NET?